# 'private set intersection on outsourced private data' - Is the repetition of 'private' OK?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, redundancy

As a paper title we have:

> "Delegated private set intersection on outsourced private data"

I need to know whether repeating an adjective "private" in the above title is (1) grammatically incorrect, (2) it's not read well, or (3) it's ok.

Please note that in the above title "private set intersection" is a protocol's name.

Comment: It looks fine to me, but the wording looks so specifically technical that it's hard to tell.  I would ask: is the outsourced data private?  If so, then it makes sense to say so.  Unless every kind of outsourced data is *always* private - then there's no point in saying it.

Comment: If both the intersection and the data are private, i don't see why you shouldn't use it on both.

Comment: well, in general the data can be public (if we don't say anything) or private.

Comment: @MorganFR To clarify, you mean repeating is ok?

Comment: Yes, repeating private here is OK because they are both in fact independently private, and one or the other could possibly be public (or whatever the default is) if not mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If the words are used correctly, there is no problem with re-using them.  I used to work at a large UK bank and one of my co-workers was an "Assistant assistant manager".